# High throughput vs low latency in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, low-latency, throughput

I tried to define what the high throughput vs low latency means in HDFS in my own words, and came up with the following definition:

> HDFS is optimized to access batches of data set quicker (high
>   throughput), rather then particular records in that data set (low
>   latency)

Does it make sense? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think what you've described is more like the difference between optimizing for different access patterns (sequential, batch vs random access) than the difference between throughput and latency in the purest sense.

When I think of a high latency system, I'm not thinking about which record I'm accessing, but rather that accessing any record at all has a high overhead cost. Accessing even just the first byte of a file from HDFS can take around a second or more.

If you're more quantitatively inclined, you can think about the total time required to access a number of records N as `T(N)=aN+b`. Here, `a` represents throughput, and `b` represents latency. With a system like HDFS, N is often so large that `b` becomes irrelevant and tradeoffs favoring a low `a` are beneficial. Contrast that to a low-latency data store, where often each read is only accessing a single record, and then optimizing for low `b` is better.

With that said, your statement isn't incorrect; it's definitely true, and it is often the case that batch access stores have high latency and high throughput, whereas random access stores have low latency and low throughput, but this is not strictly always the case.

Comment: This little equation is the most awesome way to explain it :)

Comment: @Joe K So w.r.t hadoop (or any other distributed system) is it fair to say that one needs to scale up (i.e. faster hardware) to improve latency and scale out (i.e. add more node) to improve throughput?

Comment: Yes, I would say that's probably fair for Hadoop HDFS, though other distributed systems can have vastly different performance tradeoffs. And you will get diminishing returns scaling up; HDFS is fundamentally not intended for low latency.

Comment: Isnt T(N) = N/a + b ?

Answer (score 4):

I'll take a swing at this one.

Low latency data access:  I hit the enter key (or submit button) and I
expect results within seconds at most.  My database query time should be
sub-second.
High throughput of data:  I want to scan millions of rows of data and count
or sum some subset.  I expect this will take a few minutes (or much longer
depending on complexity) to complete.  Think of more batch style jobs.

Caveats: This is really a map/reduce issue also.  The Set up and processing
of M/R jobs takes a bit of overhead.  There are a couple of projects
working now to move toward lower latency data access.

Also, HDFS stores data in blocks and distributes them across many nodes.
 This means that there will (almost) always be some network data transfer
required to get the final answer, and that "slows" things down a bit,
depending on throughput and various other factors.

Hope that helps. :)